# Using Google Drive SDK with metro app

Tags: microsoft-metro, google-drive-api

I am trying to use the google drive SDK with a metro app. The metro app connects to google drive using REST services. The first problem I am facing is in authentication. Metro app has a redirect URI which follows microsoft specific scheme like "ms-app://s-1-15-2-1527804777-383724396-285855344-2678584489-1963608684-3789894444-799666712/".

How can I register this URI with my Google app profile? Google has made it compulsory to register the redirect URI, I don't know why. No other provider (like dropbox/skydrive) does this.

Could anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect URI is part of the OAuth 2.0 spec, which is an open standard and critical to the security of the system. If other providers are performing OAuth 2.0 without this, they are insecure. Worse, if other providers are forcing apps to get usernames and passwords from users, that is bad too.

For installed apps, you can use the [Installed Application Flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp), with a local web server (localhost URI), or with the "out of band" URI, `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`. Having said that, I never tried with a metro device, perhaps others can suggest how to [perform OAuth 2.0 on metro](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122).

As per the OAuth 2.0 spec:

> When registering a client, the client developer SHALL:
>
> ```
>   o  specify the client type as described in Section 2.1,
>   o  provide its client redirection URIs as described in Section 3.1.2, and
>   o  include any other information required by the authorization server
>   (e.g. application name, website, description, logo image, the
>   acceptance of legal terms).
> ```

Comment: Probably you did not get what I said or I was not clear. I said, other providers do not ask to register the redirect URI while generating the client key. Why Google is trying to limit that? Like other providers, I should be able to provide any redirect URI in my app.

Comment: Neither of these methods works with metro app. A metro app can not listen on a local webserver (esp. on a arm tablet) and if I use urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob how do I communicate the access token back to the application? Metro app shows the access token on web page in this case.

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstanding. The client ID and client secret are meaningless without a redirect URI, they are linked.

Comment: I updated with a link, which might help you. In the oob case, the user can paste the token into your app. It is a one-time setup procedure. I will investigate to see if the ms-app:// URI is something we would consider making possible.

Comment: I am unable to understand why they should be linked. I understand that redirect URI is necessary but why should user be forced to use limited URIs with a given client ID.

Comment: Because as per the specification for OAuth 2.0, the redirect URI must be checked against the client ID. Want me to dig it up for you to see?

Comment: Check this example app: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122

Comment: Asking users to copy-paste the code will look very very awkward. I can not show any message on the web-page, how the user will know that he has to perform this copy paste somewhere?

Comment: I am using the same method which you posted and the problem remains. How should I provide the redirect URIs Google does not allow ms-app:/// scheme and Metro does not understand others?

Comment: I pasted the part of the spec, as I say, if providers are not asking you to do this, they are insecure.